# How to make a customized Preference selection

Tags: java, android, checkbox, settings

Hello any idea how I can put 3 checkboxes under another checkbox? Kind of like the 3 checkboxes are a subcategory of the main checkbox. Any help is appreciated!! (This is for Preferences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xml has a checkbox that enables/disables (android:dependency="activate_export") three checkbox below.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:disableDependentsState="false"
    android:key="activate_export"
    android:summary="@string/activate_export_summary"
    android:title="@string/activate_export_title" />


<PreferenceCategory
    android:dependency="activate_export"
    android:key="@string/export_pdf"
    android:title="@string/pref_cat_ImportExport_Summary" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:dependency="activate_export"
        android:key="export_pdf"
        android:title="@string/export_pdf" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:dependency="activate_export"
        android:key="export_ppt"
        android:title="@string/export_ppt" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:dependency="activate_export"
        android:key="export_html"
        android:title="@string/export_html" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```